# blog without any server side scripting, is it a good idea?

Tags: jquery-ui, frontend, backend, comments

I am planning to build a website. I can build the front end with html,css and javascript with the help of twitter bootstrap and jquery ui. Actually i have done a bit of work and it looks good to me.

But I am short of knowledge in case of server side language, (just learning python and django in fact).
So is it advised to build by blog without the database things and all? or should i delay it by 3-4 months until i learn server side programming?

Can I do thing like searching posts, sorting them , comment on post with out the use of databases?

Is it easy to transform my blog to a database based one in later stage easily without taking it off the web?
**ps:** i dont want to use blogging platforms like wordpress.

Comment: how/where will you store the content of the blog/posts etc. ?

Comment: in plain html pages on the hosting space

Comment: so the browser client has write access to the hosting space ?

Comment: no i guess..i will upload the files via ftp client

Comment: then that is not really a blog (blogs are usually edited/authored/commented on via borwser)... what you describe is just a static website with the looks of a blog... that is certainly possible although you will have a tough time getting global searches (searching multiple documents/posts) to work... similar problem with comments etc.

Comment: ok i will use the word website then :/

Comment: it is not about "words" - I don't understand what you want to achieve ? a blog ? or just something that looks like a blog without much functionality ?

Comment: well i want to build a my second site which i want to be more functional that the first one (which was one a one pager). It doesn't have to be a blog. It will be a multi section website where viewers cant comment on posts and all.

Comment: ok - and what is exactly your question ? just go ahead and build whatever you want to build...

Comment: i have no specific interest other than testing the front-end developing skills i have learned in the last 2 months and refining them.That is the ultimate goal actually. :)

Comment: ok - but still: what exactly is your question ?

Comment: my question is how to build the comment system without the backend stuff? and if i want a database in future how to go about it?

Comment: that is far too general to be a question for SO.

Comment: Is static-site blogging software relevant here? I've experimented with `Jekyll`. I think it works with client-side scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make a website using static web pages. But that wont be really good enough for your users or readers. Besides that you really have to put a lot of time in manually writing the code for each page.
But if you choose to build a dynamic blog that will be better for the readers. You deploy functions like search , comment  more easily.
Using a free and open source blogging platform like wordpress will cut down your task. It has ready made themes, plug ins available to get your tasks done and customize your site the way you want.Again it will be far more secure and attractive.
So my suggestion will be to go with wordpress.
And as far as the learning par is  concerned you will learn more stuff while working with wordpress than building a static site